# Get mutual friends from Facebook friends (MySQL table)

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I'm trying to get mutual friends between 2 people.
I've saved the persons friends in a table called "friends" with the following fields:

id | facebook_id | name | uid | timestamp

- id = unique id for the record
- facebook_id = the friends facebook id
- name = the friends name
- uid = the users uid on my site, which is a friend to the person saved in the table
- timestamp = don't need to explain :-)

Hope it make sense, have tried various ways to get the friends, but without luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if using subqueries would be faster or mySQL already optimizes it.
Solution with subqueries:

```
  SELECT f1.id, f1.name 
  FROM (SELECT id, name FROM friends WHERE uid=1) f1 
  JOIN (SELECT id, name FROM friends WHERE uid=2) f2 
  ON f1.id=f2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if MySQL has an `INTERSECT` operator, but...

You can grab all the friends of one person:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM friends
WHERE uid = 1
```

You could then JOIN this list back to the friends table, looking for the same friend for the other user:

```
SELECT f1.id, f1.name
FROM friends f1
  JOIN friends f2 on f1.id = f2.id
WHERE f1.uid = 1
and f2.uid = 2
```

It's pseudo-code, but it should be close.

Comment: I've tried you code, but I'm getting a "SQL syntax" error. Any idea why?

Comment: I think, I've modified the code, so it should work, but it doesn't. Do you have a example in use or something close?

Comment: Give me just a minute to hack into your machine to get the new query from you, since you didn't want to post it for us to fix syntax errors.

Comment: Sorry ;-)
Here is the code
`$this->db->select("SELECT f1.id, f1.name FROM friends f1 JOIN friends f2 on f1.id = f2.id WHERE f1.uid = 3 and f2.uid = 4"); 
  $query = $this->db->get();`

Comment: I have 2 users in the "users" table, which have ID 3 and 4 in the friends table

Comment: I made a test table (id, uid, name) and your query compiled.  What syntax error are you getting?

Comment: This error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.id, `f1`.`name` FROM friends f1 JOIN friends f2 on f1.id = f2.id WHERE f1.uid =' at line 1

SELECT `SELECT` f1.id, `f1`.`name` FROM friends f1 JOIN friends f2 on f1.id = f2.id WHERE f1.uid = 3 and f2.uid = 4

Comment: Does it really say "SELECT SELECT f1.id" ?